# How to Create line chart, column chart and pie charts in C# using Dev Express XRChart?

Tags: c#, charts, devexpress

[Want to create chart like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3LeA.png)

[Want to create pie chart like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tx7bF.png)

```
Piece of code I'm trying to write
XRChart chart = new XRChart();
                    chart.WidthF = width;
                    chart.HeightF = width;
                    chart.BorderWidth = 3;
                    chart.Borders = BorderSide.All;
                    chart.Visible = true;
```

Please check and let me know the code/example in c# to create charts using dev express.

Comment: Whats the exact problem you're facing? I guess as you use XRChart you want charting in a report. What have you tried so far? Have you checked the documentation at [devexpress](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/2609/detailed-guide-to-devexpress-reporting/use-report-controls/use-charts/use-charts-in-reports)?

Comment: it is done now. after i went through their documentation. thanks